# target= "_blank" opening new blank pages in Edge

Tags: javascript, html, forms, microsoft-edge

I have a form with action page and target as _blank. I have a submit input. I want the new form to be displayed in new page, thus I used _blank as target.

This is properly working in all browser except Edge. Blank pages are opened in MS Edge instead of action link. Is _blank not supported in edge? How do I fix this in Edge? I am using Microsoft Edge 40.15063.674.0

```
<form name="textform" action="https://local.worldlingo.com/SVZzHbqCKIvXetXPYQGYntlwJInOOQpml/translate" method="post" target="_blank">
    <script language="javascript"> <!--
    function validate(form) {
      if ((form["wl_url"].value == "") || (form["wl_url"].value == "http://")) {
        alert("Please enter a valid URL.");
        form["wl_url"].focus();
        return false;
      }
      selIndex1 = form["wl_srclang"].selectedIndex;
      selIndex2 = form["wl_trglang"].selectedIndex;
      if (form["wl_srclang"].options[selIndex1].value == form["wl_trglang"].options[selIndex2].value) {
        alert("Please select two different languages.");
        form["wl_trglang"].focus();
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
    function showhide(id){ 
      if (document.getElementById) { 
        obj = document.getElementById(id); 
        if (obj.style.display == "none") { 
          obj.style.display = ""; 
        } else { 
          obj.style.display = "none"; 
        } 
      } 
    }
    //-->
    </script>
    <div class="urlForm">
        <input type="hidden" id="wl_info" name="wl_info" value="P266681">
            <p class="normal_text">
                <select name="wl_srclang" class="trg_select">    
                    <option value="auto">Auto Detect</option>
                    <option value="GOOGLE_AF">Afrikaans</option>
                    <option value="GOOGLE_YI">Yiddish</option>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Translate" class="input" onclick="return validate(this.form);">
            </p><br> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What do you mean by "Blank pages are opened in MS Edge instead of action link"?

Comment: @TylerH the address bar in new tab is supposed to have redirected to the action link . However in Edge will have blank in address bar and page title is "Blank Page".

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the famous Edge.

Try this:

```
function isBrowserEDGE(){
 return /Edge\/\d./i.test(navigator.userAgent)
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(isBrowserEDGE()) {
        $('a').attr('download','download');
    } else {
        $('a').attr('target','_blank');
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing and why?

Comment: This will check if the current browser is Edge on load it will replace the target blank with download something similar which will not open a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

With the code you provided, I didn't reproduce the issue in my side. When I submit the form, the action link will show up in a new tab in Edge like this: [Example gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qybe.gif). And my Edge version is 44.18362.1.0.

I searched online and find a similar issue in [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2a99774-a7bb-4d87-9e3e-997fc05a6bf6/edge-browser-submit-an-html-form-with-target-quotblankquot-over-ssl-does-not-create-post?forum=win10itprogeneral). You could also check if there's something wrong with SSL in your website and use F12 to check if there's any error in console.

As a workaround, you could use the following code to open the action link in a new tab:

```
<script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    function subform() {
        $("#a").attr("target", "_blank").submit(); 
    }            
</script>

<form name="textform" action="https://local.worldlingo.com/SVZzHbqCKIvXetXPYQGYntlwJInOOQpml/translate" method="post" id="a" onsubmit="subform();">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Translate" class="input" >
</from>
```

If all the above don't work, please try to install the latest version of Edge and test it again.